# How to display title bar on loading google map

Tags: android, titlebar

The Google map was displayed but on loading the map, the title bar gets disappeared. 
Is there any solution to display the title bar?

```
private void calc_short_Distance() {
        String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + currentLatitude+","+currentLongitude+"&daddr="+fixedLatitude+","+fixedLongitude;
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        //***Title bar displayed upto here and after loading intent it disappear
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Manifest code is [here](http://pastie.org/4828812) and main activity class is [here](http://pastie.org/4829043).

Comment: You should post your code (xml and java) as part of your question - but not the entire code, only relevant parts.

Comment: @AleksG I had added the code also..

Comment: You are opening default Browser or Default Map App. it is not part of your application so u can't show titlebar in other's app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title bar is not shown over the map because you open the map as the Maps application.  Now when the map is displayed, it's not your application any more, but instead Google's app.  If you want to control how the map is shown, then you need to create your own activity with a `MapView` on it and use `MapView` API to draw your directions, etc.  Your pseudo-XML may look like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- 
    Whatever you want at the top
    -->

    <MapView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you'll need to create your activity by extending `MapActivity` and using this XML for its content view.  You can then use the `MapView` API to display any overlays you need.  You'll also need to obtain an API key to use with maps.  Have a look at [Google's MapView tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) for more information on how to code this activity.

Once you have the map activity, then use the intent to start this map activity instead of the google map app.